# Printer on CUPS installed, but won't print

Tags: drivers, server, printing, canon

This issue really annoys me. I got a new printer and want to make a network printer through my home server running Ubuntu server.

CUPS installation went fine, I connected the printer to the server by USB and added it to CUPS via web interface. The printer got recognized (there was USB:  radiobutton), but then I was supposed to specify the printer model - mine wasn't listed there. So I chose a different, yet similar model (mine is Canon LBP7100, so I tried the LBP family models). But when I try to print something, it sits in the queue for a while, then the task vanishes and that's about it. No error, no printing, no nothing.

I then tried to connect it directly to my Kubuntu laptop. The weird thing is, the printer doesn't get detected at all. Not only in the GUI Printer manager, but not even X-wise (I ran `tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log`) - all USB devices do something (even if they're not recognized), but the printer doesn't cause anything at all.

So, there are two questions, really: how do I set up a printer with no drivers (there are ones for windows), and secondly, what's the deal with the printer not appearing in X log at all? I'd expect regular GUI system to notify me of connected devices :/

Comment: open http://localhost:631/ in browser and take a look at the printer configuration

Comment: I can configure the printer with no problems, but still it won't print - I can't find which driver to use when my exact model isn't supported.

Comment: post your model, maybe i can help you

Comment: Canon LBP7100Cn. I digged around the internet and found LBP7200, but that didn't work. I wonder if there really is such a big difference they can't just make it compatible :(

Comment: did you recognize this article: http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/